# Controller is not getting called in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on angular js app. I am unable to call my controller in my app on click of button submit. Please check below sample code:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="adminsuite">
<head>
    <meta charset ="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

**login.html**

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<h2>Login</h2>
<form name="form" ng-submit='login()' role="form">
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required }">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" ng-model="username" required />
        <span ng-show="form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required" class="help-block">Username is required</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required }">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" ng-model="password" required />
        <span ng-show="form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required" class="help-block">Password is required</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="button" ng-disabled="form.$invalid" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**index.js**

```
window.onpopstate = function (e) { window.history.forward(1); }
require('jquery/dist/jquery.js');
 require('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
 require('./content/common.css');
require('angular');
require('angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js');
 require('angular-route/angular-route.js');
require('angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js');
angular.module('adminsuite',  ['ui.router','ngCookies']).config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
$stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'Login/login.html',
        controller: 'loginController'
    })
    // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
    .state('dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html',
    });

    // ABOUT PAGE AND MULTIPLE NAMED VIEWS =================================

});
require('./Login/loginController.js');

require('./services/loginAuthenticationService.js');
require('./services/UserServices.js');
```

**loginController.js**

```
angular
    .module('adminsuite')
    .controller('loginController', ['$location', '$rootScope', 'AuthenticationService', '$scope', '$state', function($location, AuthenticationService, $scope, $state) {
    $scope.login = function(){
        $scope.dataLoading = true;
        AuthenticationService.Login($scope.username, $scope.password, function (response) {
            if (response.success) {
                AuthenticationService.SetCredentials($scope.username, $scope.password);
                console.log('Login successful');
                //$rootScope.state = true;
                $state.go('dashboard');
            } else {
                console.log(response.message);
                $scope.dataLoading = false;
                //$rootScope.state = false;
            }
        });
    };
 }
```

]);

I am not getting any error in console section of browser or in command prompt.

Comment: where are you routing to login page ?

Comment: Your `Login` button should have `type='submit'` instead of `type='button'`

Comment: Your code is seem well. But You should remove type="button" from your html because Button default property is submit. for debugging you can create a fiddle

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but I don't see how/where the `index.js` is being referenced/invoked. I always deploy a `console.log` at the beginning of each and every controller to make sure it is loaded correctly.

Comment: Using bundle.js am referencing index.js into my project. I did this by using webpack.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the login button in `login.html` to have `type="submit"` instead of `type="button"`:

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
```

Comment: I changed the button type to 'submit', then also it is not working.

Comment: Am not getting any kind of console error or anything. That is why i am unable figure it out

Comment: If you add a `console.log` on the first line of `$scope.login`, does it show up? Just to make sure this isn't a problem in your AuthenticationService. Try adding a `console.log` line on the first row of your loginController function, too, to check that the controller is actually being initialized. Also, make sure the old login.js isn't being cached, so check that the button is actually of type='submit' with the browser html inspector. Other than those, dunno what could be the issue...

Comment: As you said i have added this line code console.log('start'); before $scope.login, it is showing in the console but again on click of that button it is not getting trigger the controller. It was working previously today only am facing this issue.

Comment: Thank you, i figured this out. In the login controller am injecting the $rootScope but am not passing into the function parameter. I just removed it and it worked. Thing is that this issue they are not showing any error.

Comment: Ah, I see! Glad you figured it out anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Just removed the $rootScope injector from controller as it is not passed as parameter to the controller function.And it worked

Answer (score 0):

> you did not assign your controller in the html part try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="adminsuite">
<head>
    <meta charset ="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="loginController">
<script src="bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: He defined it in ui-router config, so no need of ng-controller

Comment: `ui-router` is taking care of that